# Jython: Import Modules From Other Sources (DB for instance)?

Tags: module, import, load, hook, jython

I'm using a Java program to load and run Jython scripts - using the org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.

I'm storing the Jython scripts in a database : currently I'm having to extract the Python scripts to a file system prior to running them - to ensure that any 'import' statements within the scripts work.

Is there a way of avoiding this extraction step: that is - is there a way to hook into the Python interpreter to intercept the imports and call out to a Java Method (which would load the jython source from the DB) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add importers from either Python or Java (there's a standard one in the Jython code which imports from the classpath: `org.python.core.ClasspathPyImporter`; there's also some Javadocs in the `org.python.core.util.importer` interface it implements which may be useful).  The code is relatively simple; see [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) as well.

Comment: Thanks for that (+1) - I'm holding off accepted answer for a bit: would like to see if somebody can provide an simplified example of what I actually need to implement - not clear from the javadocs what I actually need to do ! Cheers